Barret Reduction code for Kyber
I am trying to perform a "Barret reduction" for kyber code and need a mod3329 function. I came across the below code:
 #define MOD_VALUE 3329
 int16_t barrett_reduce(int16_t a) {
    // First adjustment
    const int16_t v = ((1<<26) + MOD_VALUE/2)/MOD_VALUE;
    int32_t t = ((int32_t)v*a + (1<<25)) >> 26;
    t *= MOD_VALUE;
    a -= t;
    
    // 2nd adjustment
    // Time-constant reduction using bit manipulation
    int16_t mask = a >> 15;  // All 1s if negative, all 0s if non-negative
    a += ((MOD_VALUE & mask) | (0 & ~mask));

    // 3rd adjustment
    mask = -(a >= MOD_VALUE );  // All 1s if a >= MOD_VALUE, all 0s otherwise
    a -= (MOD_VALUE & mask);

    return a;

}
I am finding it difficult to understand why are the below lines needed as the result after 2nd adjustment guarantee result < MOD_VAL  ?
    mask = -(a >= MOD_VALUE );
    a -= (MOD_VALUE & mask);


In C true (for an inequality) is represented by the value $1$, and false by the value $0$. Does this help?

The code computes the mathematical reminder of $a$ divided by $\mathtt{\text{MODVALUE}}=n=3329$, noted $r:=a\bmod n$, that is integer $r$ such that $0\le r<n$ and $a-r=q\;\!n$ for some integer $q$. I blindly assume this is what's desired.
For $n=3329$ and the code as is, it does so correctly for the $2^{16}$ values of input integer $a$ in $[-2^{15},2^{15})$.

In a first step, an approximation $t$ of quotient $q$ is estimated as
$$t=\left\lfloor\frac{v\;\!a+2^{25}}{2^{26}}\right\rfloor$$
(where the $2^{25}$ term is large enough that the numerator of the fraction is never negative) for some constant $v$ precomputed as
$$v=\left\lfloor\frac{2^{26}+\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor}n\right\rfloor$$
In a first adjustment, it's computed $r:=a-t\;\!n$
Note: I'll keep noting $a$ and $t$ for what's first computed for these, and is no longer in variables a and t. I use $r$ for the value in variable a after the first adjustment.
A second adjustment adds $n$ to $r$ if $r<0$, because $t=q+1$.
Note: the test for negative uses that in 2-s complement notation used by most modern computers for signed integers, the high order bits of integers is 1 for strictly negative integers (or equivalently that negative signed integers are converted to unsigned by adding $2^k$ where $k$ is the bit width). These negative bits (at least 12 to fully cover $\mathtt{\text{MODVALUE}}=n=3329$) are brought to the right by shifting. Even though variable a (now holding $r$) is 16 bits, there are enough mask bits, because in a >> 15 the variable a is extended to int by C promotion rules before the shift (the code clearly assumes the compiler has at-least 32-bit int since 1<<26 is uses for $2^{26}$). For some compilers with 16-bit int a >> 15 would still work due to a not-quite-portable but common feature of C that right-shifting signed integers leaves their high-order bit unchanged (the so-called arithmetic shift).
Note: the whole second adjustment can be simplified to a += (a>>15)&MOD_VALUE;
A third adjustment subtracts $n$ from $r$ if $r\ge n$, because $t=q-1$. But it turns out this can't happen with the constants at hand and the two lines under // 3rd adjustment are not necessary. That's because the estimation of $t$ happens to always be by excess (or exact). The main reason for this is that the rounding in the computation of $v$ happens to be such that $v\;\!n>2^{26}$; but that would not hold for other nearby values of $n$.

Note: the code attempts to be free of data-dependent timing variations, and in that respect the expression a >= MOD_VALUE in the third adjustment is suspicious (or rather would be if that condition was not always false, as it is). But the (32-bit) multiplications v*a and t *= MOD_VALUE also are suspicious to a degree, see this. For more robust code when it comes to avoiding data-dependent timing variations, t could be estimated using additions and shifts.
Here is a suggested replacement with exactly the original code's functionality, entirely free from multiplications, typically free from data-dependent timing variation, with test code. Try it online!
#include <stdint.h>

// compute r in [0,3329) such that a-r is a multiple of 3329
int16_t reduce3329(int16_t a) {
    uint32_t b = a+33290;               // non-negative with same remainder
    uint32_t q = ((b<<2)+b)>>14;        // (5*b)/(1<<14) is quotient by excess 
    b -= (q<<11)+(q<<10)+(q<<8)+q;      // subtract 3329*q
    return (int16_t)(((b>>16)&3329)+b); // correction for negative
}

// validation code for the above, showing first error
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int16_t a = 0;                      // start testing from 0
    do {
        int16_t r = reduce3329(a);      // result obtained
        int16_t s = (a+332900)%3329;    // correct result
        if (r != s)
            return printf("### fail for %d yielding %d instead of %d\n",(int)a,(int)r,(int)s), 1;
    } while(++a);                       // test every valid int16_t
    return printf("# pass\n"), 0;
}


regarding timing constant i am not sure, i took the reference from kyber repo : https://github.com/pq-crystals/kyber/blob/main/ref/reduce.c#L35

a += ((MOD_VALUE & mask) | (0 & ~mask)); can be modified to a += ((MOD_VALUE & mask)); ?

@the whole | (0 & ~mask) thing can't do anything (because the parenthesis evaluates to zero, and then | 0 does nothing but perhaps a type conversion). It is best removed. Many compilers not in debug mode will do that anyway.
